# Saving strings into a ResourceDictionary in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

Every time I program in C#, I write the UI strings into my WPF code. I don't think that's the best practice for writing the UI strings. Is it possible to save all of them into a [ResourceDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references)? This way they are all stored in a single file and not the code. It would probably also be easier to change strings later on.

How could I achieve something like this? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean "output string for the users "

Comment: @esiprogrammer strings that will be shown on the UI like "Login in".

Comment: You can use the [ResourceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) which has one or more resx files as datasource for the strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup will be the same whether you have a console application or wpf or web. What you need to do is to add resource files. To practice and get started, you can create a console application and then:

1. Double click "properties" node of the project in the solution explorer.
2. Click "Resources" tab.
3. Click the link to create the resource file.
4. In the Name column enter "Hello". This will be used in code to refer to this translation. In the value column enter "Hello". This is what the users will see.
5. Note that a file named Resources.resx has been created under the properties node.
6. Right click the properties node and select Add > New Item. Select Resources File and name this file exactly this: Resources.fr.resx. (fr stands for french)
7. In the Name column enter "Hello". This will be used in code to refer to this translation. In the value column enter "Bonjour". This is what the users will see.

Now in the main method add the following code:

```
// Default local on my OS is En (English). If it was French it will say "Bonjour" instead.
Console.WriteLine(Resources.Hello);
// Now we change it to French so you can see how it picks the right string based on the language
// See fr in line below. This will pick up the Resources.fr.resx instead of Resources.resx
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
Console.WriteLine(Resources.Hello);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Run the application and the output will be:

Hello
Bonjour

It would be the same idea in WPF but instead of Console.WriteLine you will use it differently. For example:

```
Title="{x:Static p:Resources.Hello}" Height="350" Width="525">
```